# Best way to indicate that some lines are left out

Tags: listings, best-practices, code

Assume I wrote a class `myclass` in Matlab with many properties and methods, and now I want to display

- its most important properties (`foo` and `bar`),
- the headers of its most important methods (`myclass` and `baz`) together with
- their documentation and
- one line that summarizes the steps.

Which is the best way to indicate that some lines of the original source code were left out, as it was done here in lines 6, 11 and 15?

#### Current Output

[image: Output of the MWE]

#### MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.m}
classdef myclass
    % MYCLASS A very good class.
    properties
        foo
        bar
        ... and many more.
    end
    methods
        function mc = myclass(foo, bar)
            % MYCLASS Construct an instance of this class.
            ... check for allowed input, accept input.
        end
        function baz(mc)
            % BAZ Does something great.
            ... print info.
        end
    end
end
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=matlab,
    numbers=left,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue!75!black},
    commentstyle=\color{green!50!black},
    morecomment=[l]{...},
    morekeywords={classdef,methods,properties},
    deletekeywords={bar},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]{See my code}
        \lstinputlisting{\jobname.m}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to define an escape character and use it to highlight the omitted text. For example adding to the `lsset`

```
escapechar={|},
```

and then using

```
|\color{red}... check for allowed input, accept input.|
```

[image: a]

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.m}
    classdef myclass
    % MYCLASS A very good class.
    properties
    foo
    bar
    |\color{red}... and many more.|
    end
    methods
    function mc = myclass(foo, bar)
    % MYCLASS Construct an instance of this class.
    |\color{red}... check for allowed input, accept input.|
    end
    function baz(mc)
    % BAZ Does something great.
    ... print info.
    end
    end
    end
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=matlab,
    numbers=left,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue!75!black},
    commentstyle=\color{green!50!black},
    escapechar={|}, % added <<<<<<<<<<
    morekeywords={classdef,methods,properties},
    deletekeywords={bar},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]{See my code}
        \lstinputlisting{\jobname.m}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can accommodate a block of code using a `minipage`[image].

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.m}
    classdef myclass
    % MYCLASS A very good class.
    properties
    foo
    bar
    |\color{red}... and many more.|
    end
    methods
    function mc = myclass(foo, bar)
    % MYCLASS Construct an instance of this class.
    |\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}       
    \color{red}... check for allowed input, accept input. \\
        more lines of code \\
        more lines of code\\
        more lines of code
    \end{minipage}|
    end
    function baz(mc)
    % BAZ Does something great.
    ... print info.
    end
    end
    end
\end{filecontents*}
```